# How can "bad" views be identified?

Tags: teradata

At my workplace, we have separate Teradata databases to manage tables versus views.  The "tables" database has tables with data while the "views" database has only views.  Access to the two databases is managed by roles:  "Developers" have permission to create tables in "tables" and create views in "views"; "Consumers" have only "read" access to the "views" databases.

Over time, some views have become "bad" in that the base tables they refer to no longer exist.  This usually is caused when the developer dropped the table at the end of some analysis and forgot to drop the corresponding view.

**Question:** Is there an "easy" way to identify views that are no longer associated with valid tables?

I am considering writing a test script to execute a `select count(*)` on each view in the "views" database; if the test fails I'd know something was wrong with the view.  I know how to do this (and it would work), but I thought I'd ask if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written up an approach that can be used to find broken views [here](http://robpaller.com/archive/2012/09/finding-broken-views-in-teradata/). By using a stored procedure, a couple of cursors, and the `PREPARE` statement you can quickly test the validity of the views across the entire data warehouse.

The biggest trick is getting the error handler nailed down to log your errors. While I didn't go into the details on my website about the error handler, if you get stuck I can send you some pseudo-code to get down the right path.